# Use Svelte i18n in service / simple JS file

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

I use Svelte i18n for my project, it works perfectly in my Svelte components.

But I have some JS files (for constants for example), I want to use i18n to translate some keys, like (in `/services/constants.js`) :

```
import { _ } from 'svelte-i18n'

export const STATUS_OK = 1;
export const STATUS_PENDING = 2;
export const STATUS_ERROR = 3;
export const STATUS_INACTIVE = 4;
export const STATUS_PRICE_NOT_FOUND = 5;

export const STATUTES = {
  [STATUS_OK]: {
    text: _('urls.statutes.ok'),
    class: 'text-green-500',
  },
```

But I got an error, can I use `_` function in a JS file ? Or should I create kind of svelte component to handle my constants ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I understood the way `svelte-i18n` works correctly, `_` is a *store*, and this is why you can do the following in a component

```html
<p>{$_('urls.statuses.ok')}</p>
```

The `$` creates a subscription and get's the current value of the store, on which you execute a function to get the given key.

In your code you do `_('urls.statuses.ok')` which is a function you are trying to execute on the **store** and not on the **value of the store**.  And it is this 'value' that actually provides you with the functionality of internationalization.

You cannot use `$` in a javascript file though, so here you are left with two options:

**use get()**

You can `import { get } from 'svelte/store'` this gives you a function that would return the current value of a store, meaning you could change your code to look like this:

```
text: get(_)('urls.statuses.ok')
```

One downside of this is that it doesn't create a subscription, or in other words, if the language changes this constant will not change because `get` doesn't run again, it only ran once.

**return a function from text**

The other option is a bit of a bigger change namely redefining `text` as a function

```
text: _ => _('urls.statuses.ok')
```

Here we pass the store into the function from outside inside of importing it directly into the javascript file. The usage would be

```
<p>{STATUTES.STATUS_OK($_)}</p>
```

As you see, we pass the *value of the store* into the function, meaning that inside the function we can use our store as expected and because when the language change, this block will be re-evaluated, it will always get the *current* language instead of the initial one like we got with `get`.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from Stephane Vanraes is right, but there is a solution from svelte-i18n

```
import { unwrapFunctionStore, format, formatNumber } from 'svelte-i18n';

const $formatNumber = unwrapFunctionStore(formatNumber);
const $format = unwrapFunctionStore(format);
```

See FAQ: https://github.com/kaisermann/svelte-i18n/blob/main/docs/FAQ.md#can-i-use-the-formatter-functions-outside-of-a-svelte-component